# URL names for Google services

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I know that in order to download a cookie associated with an account using PHP we could use CURL to get:

`https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=##youremail##&Passwd=##yourpassword##&service=##service-name##&source=test-test-v1`

But I have no idea what the URL codes for the different services are (what we would replace ##service-name## with in the URL above). Does anyone know the names for the different services? More specifically, does anyone know the name of the one for AdWords and/or the AdWords Keyword Tool?

Comment: _Don't do this_.  Use Google's actual APIs.  (and OAuth)

Comment: It would be for my personal research, I just don't want to have to pay the API fees for something only I myself am going to use.

Comment: @SLaks but the ClientLogin API is perfect for single-serving applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a post that is perfect for this at http://codecri.me/case/429/list-of-google-services-service-names/